Folder Size is too Large of Lucene Documents
I am using the following code to add documents to a Lucene index. I have indexed 23,425 documents, but the folder where the index is stored has a size of 447.4 MB. In contrast, when storing the same data in a Parquet file with the same 23,425 records, the file size is only 625 KB. The folder size for the Lucene index seems excessively large. Could someone help identify why this is happening and how to optimize it? Below is the code I am using:
        MMapDirectory indexDirectory = new MMapDirectory(Paths.get(directory));
        // Configure the IndexWriter with an analyzer
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, config);

for (Map.Entry<String, OperationAggregation> entry : operations.entrySet())
  {
           Document doc1 = new Document();
           doc1.add(new StringField("namespace", namespace, Store.YES));
           doc1.add(new StringField("type", "operations", Store.YES));
           doc1.add(new StringField("data", entry.getKey(), Store.YES));
           doc1.add(new StringField("serviceName",entry.getValue().getServiceName(),
                                                    Store.YES));
           List<AggregationAttribute> attributes =
                                            entry.getValue().getOperationAttributes();
             for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) 
             {
                 doc1.add(new StoredField(attributes.get(i).getName(),
                               String.valueOf(attributes.get(i).getValue())));
              }
               try { docCount.getAndIncrement();
                     ndexWriter.addDocument(doc1);
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                     logger.error("Error while adding document to index", e);
                }
    }
    indexWriter.commit();
    indexWriter.close();


Not an answer, just some questions/suggestions: Why are you using StringField everywhere? Just use it where it makes sense to use it - and you should probably be using TextField most of the time, anyway. Read the Javadocs to see why.

Why are you using Store.YES everywhere? Again, use it where it makes sense to use it. Use Store.NO otherwise. See Field.Store.

There may be other issues also - for example, if you keep adding duplicate data to your index every time you run your code. Compare your approach to the official demo.

@andrewJames - I want to retrieve the original value of each field later, so I am setting it to Store.YES. I am using StringField because, as per my understanding, the index size is smaller for StringField (since no tokenization is performed), while the index size is larger for TextField (due to tokenization and indexing). Please correct me if I am wrong. Also I cofirmed there is no duplicate data .

You appear to be mis-using Lucene. For example, you won't be able to do any full-text searching with this approach - which is generally the whole point in using Lucene in the first place. I think you might need to add a lot more clarification to your question, to improve your chances of getting a helpful and relevant answer.

Sure , I will add more details. Thank You @andrewJames.
